# Le nom « tonne » tel que décrivant une personne

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, évolution-récente, métaphore

Dans la pièce « *Cyrano de Bergerac* » d'Edmond Rostand, se trouve le nom  « *tonne* », qui est utilisé en tant que métaphore pour décrire une personne, le comédien [Montfleury](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montfleury), un acteur du 17<sup>e</sup> siècle sous la protection de Richelieu, et que l'auteur met en scène un bref instant.

> **Ragueneau.**
>
> Montfleury joue !
> **Lignière.**
>
> En effet, cette tonne
> Va nous jouer ce soir le rôle de Phédon.
> Qu’importe à Cyrano ?

C'est une personne à l'embonpoint indéniable et l'on est enclin à situer la métaphore au niveau le plus grossier, c'est à dire celui auquel on ne s'attarde pas à plus que des considérations de volume physique. Malgré l'analogie avec la comparaison moderne où on fait emploi du mot « [barrique](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barrique) » (emploi pas très raffiné, péjoratif, mais assez peu vulgaire et effectif), qui tend à confirmer l'hypothèse d'une caractérisation sur ce plan-là, c'est une idée qui ne semble pas satisfaisante en cela que le personnage de Montfleury dans la pièce est un acteur d'une certaine réputation, même si décrié par Cyrano (et par Rostand à travers lui). On peut donc être étonné, et même se demander s'il n'existe pas un autre sens, comme par exemple apparenté à celui de « sommité », de « chef de file » ou autre terme de cette sorte.

En fait, le TLFi fournit cette référence même pour illustrer le sens de « tonne ».

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tonne)) ♦ P. métaph.
> • Madame, on ne communique pas ainsi, dit le bon vieux Gault. Et il arrêta lui-même au passage cette tonne de moire noire et de dentelles (Balzac, Splend. et mis., 1847, p. 571).
>
> • Ragueneau: Montfleury joue! Lignière: En effet, cette tonne va nous jouer ce soir le rôle de Phédon (Rostand, Cyrano, 1898, I, 2, p. 23).

Le TLFi, selon le premier exemple conçoit la comparaison comme très générale, il ne s'agit que d'un volume de dentelle.

Le Wiktionnaire, qui, derechef,  prend les vers de Rostand pour référence, ajoute deux précisions très importantes.

> ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tonne)) (Familier) (Péjoratif) (Sens figuré) Individu de forte corpulence et lourdaud, bête, inapte sur le plan moral.
>
> "Montfleury joue !
> [...] En effet, cette tonne
> Va nous jouer ce soir le rôle de Phédon." — (Edmond Rostand, Cyrano de Bergerac, 1897, Acte I, scène II)

Noter que le TLFi ne fait aucune mention concernant le registre, que l'on doit de ce fait considérer comme courant.

En considération du premier exemple du TLFi (simple volume important de dentelle), on est maintenant en droit de distinguer deux sens.

1.Cela mis à part, et en considérant que le Wiktionnaire capture ce sens convenablement, on ne peut pas,   en langue plus moderne, adopter la transcription « En effet, cette barrique Va nous jouer ce soir le rôle de Phédon. ».
Existe-t-il un terme plus récent qui lie ces deux idées, obésité, et, dans l'ensemble, bêtise ?  (Soit dit en passant de cette association qu'elle est incongrue et tout à fait au détriment de ce terme.)
2. S'il s'agit d'un autre sens quel est-il ?

Comment: Flaubert emploie à plusieurs reprises la locution  Tonner contre  Dans son inachevé Dictionnaire des idées reçues